# underline a url in android

Tags: android

I am making a android game application.I want to highlight url when running in emulator. How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

For this u observie Linkify concept.see the below link

> [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html)

```
TextView noteView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noteview);
noteView.setText(someContent);
Linkify.addLinks(noteView, Linkify.ALL);
```

Comment: if this answer is useful for u,Rate it then others also use this one